# Browserify + Babelify Gulp task is not terminating, when Watchify is used

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, browserify, babeljs

I've made a gulp task for browserify with babelify in my Angular project, which I'm developing in WebStorm. First of all, I should say, that **this code does work perfectly**.

My **browserify bundle** be like:

```
const appBundle = browserify({
    entries: config.client.src.appModule, // main angular app file 
    debug: TRUE,
    packageCache: {},
    cache: {}
}).transform(babelify, {only: './src/client'}).on('log', gutil.log);
```

And my **gulp.task** be like:

```
gulp.task('browserify', ['jshint'], function () {
        return appBundle.bundle()
            .on('error', function (err) {
                gutil.log('Browserify error: ' + gutil.colors.red(err.message));
            })
            .pipe(source('app.js')) // main dist file
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

**The issue** I can't understand at all:

My question was: *Why is my gulp task not terminating after it is through with its job?* I should always stop it manually by clicking square button in my WebStorm.

### UPDATE 1

I've figured out that the problem is eliminated if I pass "browserify" bundle directly, without the variable **appBundle**. So the code turns to:

```
browserify({
    entries: config.client.src.appModule, // main angular app file 
    debug: TRUE,
    packageCache: {},
    cache: {}
}).transform(babelify, {only: './src/client'}).on('log', gutil.log) 
  .bundle().on('error', function (err) {
         gutil.log('Browserify error: ' + gutil.colors.red(err.message));
   })
   .pipe(source('app.js')) // main dist file
   .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
```

**And it works!** But the main hardship is that i'm using this **appBundle** in my **watchify** task, so I don't want to duplicate the bundle.

### UPDATE 2

After a couple of hours I've figured out again, that's the issue was concerned with my **watchify** task. The hole code was like that:

```
const appBundle = browserify({
    entries: config.client.src.appModule, // main js file 
    debug: TRUE,
    packageCache: {},
    cache: {}
}).transform(babelify, {only: './src/client'});

const b = watchify(appBundle);

function rebundle(bundler) {
    return bundler
        .bundle()
        .on('error', function (err) {
            gutil.log('Browserify error: ' + gutil.colors.red(err.message));
        })
        .pipe(source('app.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
}

gulp.task('watchify', function () {

    rebundle(b);

    b.on('update', function () {
        rebundle(b)
    });
    b.on('log', gutil.log); // output build logs to terminal
});

gulp.task('browserify', ['jshint'], function () {
    rebundle(appBundle);
});
```

And when I've put down declaration of the `const b` into my watchify task, everything everything has started to work properly.

**But the final question is: WHY IT HAS STARTED TO WORK?**

Answer (score 0):

see this file i think it will help you

```
/*
 *  Task Automation to make my life easier.
 *  Author: Jean-Pierre Sierens
 *  ===========================================================================
 */

// declarations, dependencies
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

// Static server
gulp.task('serve', ['scripts'], function() {

    browserSync.init({
        server: "./"
    });
    gulp.watch(['./app/**/*.js'], ['scripts']);
    gulp.watch('./index.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);
   // gulp.watch("app/scss/*.scss", ['sass']);
  //  gulp.watch("app/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});
// External dependencies you do not want to rebundle while developing,
// but include in your application deployment
var dependencies = [
    'react',
    'react-dom'
];
// keep a count of the times a task refires
var scriptsCount = 0;

// Gulp tasks
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    bundleApp(false);
});

gulp.task('deploy', function (){
    bundleApp(true);
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch(['./app/*.js'], ['scripts']);
});

// When running 'gulp' on the terminal this task will fire.
// It will start watching for changes in every .js file.
// If there's a change, the task 'scripts' defined above will fire.
gulp.task('default', ['serve']);

// Private Functions
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
function bundleApp(isProduction) {
    scriptsCount++;
    // Browserify will bundle all our js files together in to one and will let
    // us use modules in the front end.
    var appBundler = browserify({
        entries: './app/app.js',
        debug: true
    })

    // If it's not for production, a separate vendors.js file will be created
    // the first time gulp is run so that we don't have to rebundle things like
    // react everytime there's a change in the js file
    if (!isProduction && scriptsCount === 1){
        // create vendors.js for dev environment.
        browserify({
            require: dependencies,
            debug: true
        })
            .bundle()
            .on('error', gutil.log)
            .pipe(source('vendors.js'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./web/js/'));
    }
    if (!isProduction){
        // make the dependencies external so they dont get bundled by the
        // app bundler. Dependencies are already bundled in vendor.js for
        // development environments.
        dependencies.forEach(function(dep){
            appBundler.external(dep);
        })
    }

    appBundler
    // transform ES6 and JSX to ES5 with babelify
        .transform("babelify", {presets: ["es2015", "react"]})
        .bundle()
        .on('error',gutil.log)
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./web/js/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, it didn't resolve my problem. I've updated the question.